# Deserialising XML element and storing value in child class field

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

When I'm converting an XML document to an instance of a `Child` Java Bean,
the annotation of `attribute` from `Parent` is always used. Resulting in `FilteredAttribute attribute` being `null`.

```
<child>
  <attribute name="firstName" />
</child>
```

How can I force `attribute` to be parsed specifically by the child? So that `FilteredAttribute attribute;` ends up containing the value.

```
@XmlTransient
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Parent {
  @XmlElement(name = "attribute")
  private List<String> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Child extends Parent {
  @XmlElement(name = "attribute")
  private FilteredAttribute attribute;
}
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FilteredAttribute {

  @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
  private String name;

  public FilteredAttribute(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are using the `@XmlElement(name = "attribute")` on both the fields in `Parent` and `Child` class. Because of it `JAXB` automatically assigns the value to the `Parent` class field.

Scenario-1
If you would like to assign the value to `Child` class field then you should remove the `@XmlElement(name = "attribute")` from the `Parent` class.

Scenario-2
Similarly other way round if you want it to be in `Parent` class `attributes` then remove `@XmlElement(name = "attribute")` from `Child` class and change the xml as well.

`Scenario-1 CODE:`

```
@XmlTransient
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Parent {

  private List<FilteredAttribute> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "child")
class Child extends Parent{
  @XmlElement(name = "attribute")
  private FilteredAttribute attribute;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class FilteredAttribute {

  @XmlAttribute
  private String name;
}

class Main1{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException, JsonProcessingException {
    //XML to JSON
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Child.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    InputStream inputStream = Main1.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Customer.xml");
    final XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    final XMLStreamReader streamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
    final Child child = unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamReader, Child.class).getValue();
    System.out.println(child.getAttribute().getName());
  }
}
```

Scenarion-1 XML:

```
<child>
  <attribute name="firstName"/>
</child>
```

`Scenario-2 CODE`:

```
@XmlTransient
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Parent {
  @XmlElementWrapper(name = "attributes")
  @XmlElement(name = "attribute")
  private List<FilteredAttribute> attributes = new ArrayList<>();
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "child")
class Child extends Parent{
  private FilteredAttribute attribute;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class FilteredAttribute {

  @XmlAttribute
  private String name;
}

class Main1{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException, JsonProcessingException {
    //XML to JSON
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Child.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    InputStream inputStream = Main1.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Customer.xml");
    final XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    final XMLStreamReader streamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
    final Child child = unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamReader, Child.class).getValue();
    System.out.println(child.getAttributes().get(0).getName());
  }
}
```

XML for scenario-2:

```
<child>
  <attributes>
      <attribute name="firstName"/>
  </attributes>
</child>
```